# Swift on iOS: ending call after user's answer

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I want to end a call just after the user has pressed the answer button. I want to do this because I need to begin another real call in my app. I'm using Swift and CallKit and I've tried this code without success

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CallKit

class TrecCall: NSObject, CXProviderDelegate {
    
    var callProvider: CXProvider?
    let callUUID = UUID(uuidString: "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000")

    var userInfoForPlugin: [String: Any]?
    
    func startCall() {
        
        let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
        let phoneNumber = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: "Trec Doc")
        callUpdate.remoteHandle = phoneNumber
        
        let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "Trec Conf")
        configuration.maximumCallGroups = 1
        configuration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
        configuration.supportsVideo = false
        configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [.generic]
        configuration.iconTemplateImageData = UIImage(named: "callkit-icon")?.pngData()
        callProvider = CXProvider(configuration: configuration)
        callProvider!.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
        
        callProvider?.reportNewIncomingCall(with: callUUID!, update: callUpdate, completion: { (error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("Starting call")
            }
        })
        
    }
    
    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {

        print("Ending call after answer")
        let controller = CXCallController()
        let transaction = CXTransaction(action: CXEndCallAction(call: callUUID!))
        controller.request(transaction,completion: { error in })
        
        action.fulfill()
        
    }
    
    func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
        
    }
    
}
```

The provider func is called when the answer button is pressed, the code works without errors but the call is not ended.

Any idea?

Thanks